# How to remove system overlay using window manager when touch outside?

Tags: android

I have created a service which opens a system overlay on the top of every app all is working fine but when i touch outside it never remove . I searched a lot but didn't find suitable answer. Pls help me out.

code:-

```
 @Override
public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d("inez", "inez onCreate");
    super.onCreate();
    mContext = getApplicationContext();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            0, 0, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH, PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
    SwitchCompat switchCompat = (SwitchCompat) view.findViewById(R.id.notification_switch);
    switchCompat.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Checked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                stopService(intent);
            }
        }
    });

    wm.addView(view, params);
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.e(TAG, "OnDestroy called::");
    super.onDestroy();
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    wm.removeView(view);
}


@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    return false;
}
```